# WordPress JS errors in Post section after upgrade to 3.5.1

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-3.5

After upgrading to WordPress Version 3.5.1, I am getting a few JS errors and hence not able to use some basic WP features in the admin panel.

E.g. On post edit page I am not able to switch the editor to html mode, not able to click on any link (Edit), tabs, etc.

Please suggest what action should be taken or is it a WordPress upgrade issue? Did a reinstall but no change.

The errors I noticed in firebug console are as follows . . . .

```
TypeError: e is undefined

TypeError: $(...).pointer is not a function $(’.insert-media’).pointer( options ).pointer(‘open’);

TypeError: switchEditors is undefined switchEditors.switchto(this);
```

Comment: Do any of your plugins, or your theme, load a non-Core version of jQuery, or any Javascript related to the editor?

Comment: Are you running any plugins?  Have you made any custom modifications to the admin area?

Comment: Is this a clean install of Wordpress? Have you tried disabling all plugins? Have you tried using a default theme (like *Twenty Twelve*)?

Comment: I was able to resolve it by updating the jQuery(latest jQuery file) in one of my plugins. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes disabling or updating plugins doesn't help because your theme is using outdated JS. For me it was jQuery-ui library, which was used by theme. If your Wordpress version is 3.5 or higher, you need to use jQuery-UI 1.9.2 or higher.

More info here: http://www.hoosoft.com/blog/fix-jquery-1-8-3-error-typeerror-e-is-undefined-in-wordpress-3-5/

Comment: I agree, I was also able to resolve it by updating the jQuery(latest jQuery file) in one of my plugins as mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: I meant using latest version of jQuery/jQuery-UI.